# sorting of cursor alphabetically is not proper in android

Tags: android, sorting, android-cursor

Hello I am creating music app.

I sorted my cursor alphabetically with the help of following line :

```
private String sortOrder = MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE + "";
c = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION + ">0", null, sortOrder);
```

This code does sorting good but the problem is it takes first all capital letter in sorting then it takes small letters in sorting like A-Z then a-z and I want to sort it like Aa - Zz.

Aa-Zz means first cursor item start with 'A' then start with 'a' then item start with 'B' and then start with 'b' and so on.

Here is the image which helps you get more on this :

[Image which shows listview in which cursor sorts music files A-Z then a-z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hadk.jpg)